# Accumulation points of accumulation points of accumulation points

Tags: general-topology

Let $A'$ denote the set of accumulation points of $A$.
Find a subset $A$ of $\Bbb R^2$ such that $A, A', A'', A'''$ are all distinct.

I can find a set $A$ such that $A$ and $A'$ are distinct, but not one where $A,A',A'',A'''$ are all distinct.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here’s a schematic of what you need to get distinct $A,A'$, and $A''$; it generalizes easily.

$$\begin{array}{rr}
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\longrightarrow&\bullet\\
\uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow&\uparrow\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet\\
\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet&\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\to\bullet
\end{array}$$

Comment: This picture is worth a thousand words (or a mess of formulas).

Comment: Cool! in LaTex..

Comment: If we let A = {(1/m,1/n) : m,n are natural numbers} then A' = {(0,1/n) : n natural number} union {(1/m,0) : m natural number}, A'' = {0} , A''' = empty set. I think this works.

Comment: @John: Yes, that appears to work. You could also expand $A$ to include all of those limit points (i.e., replace $A$ by $\operatorname{cl}A$).

Comment: Brian, you do know that we have AMScd support now for diagrams... :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Hey, I can only use what I know! I didn’t even know any $\LaTeX$ until I started posting here, not quite two years ago.

Comment: @Brian: And you're a grown up mathematician. That's a shame!

Comment: Thank you for spending your time making the diagram!

Comment: @John: You’re welcome! I like good visual aids.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Work backwards. Start with some set, then add a sequence which converges to each point, then add a sequence which converges to each of the points in *that* set, and so on.

Do this carefully and you can make sure that $A$ is such set.

If you are familiar with the concept of ordinals, then you can also consider the ordinal $\omega^4$ embedded into the real numbers.

Comment: I'm likely missing something: how is $A'$ different from the closure of $A$?

Comment: @MartinArgerami:  if $A=\{1/2,1/4,1/8,\ldots\}$, $A'=\{0\}$.  The closure of $A$ is the union of these.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The same thing confused me too, initially. It seems that (at least according to Wikipedia), $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if $x \in \overline{A\setminus\{x\}}$, i.e. there has to be a *non-trivial* sequence in $A$ which converges to $x$

Comment: @fgp: That’s correct: every open nbhd of $x$ must contain some point of $A$ **different from** $x$ in order for $x$ to be an accumulation point of $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The interesting thing is, I'm pretty sure that this isn't the definition I learned years ago. Then again, my native language is german, so maybe there's a subtle difference between "Häufungspunkt" and "accumulation point", even though the former is pretty much the direct translation of the latter. Out of curiosity - do you distinguish between "accumulation point", "limit point" and "cluster point", or are these all synonyms? 'cause they all seems to translate to "Häufungspunkt"..

Comment: @fgp: I’ve seen them used as synonyms. I prefer to use *cluster point* only in the context of sequences (and nets), so that I can say that $1$ is a cluster point of $\sigma=\langle(-1)^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ even though it’s not an accumulation (or limit) point of the range of $\sigma$. (German Wikipedia uses *Häufungspunkt* for both but carefully notes that * Folgenhäufungspunkt* and *Mengenhäufungspunkt* aren’t quite the same concept.) I do use *accumulation point* and *limit point* pretty much interchangeably, though the former has some special uses (e.g., *complete accumulation point*).

Answer (score 2):

What might be confusing here is that you won't, of course, get that $\overline{A} \neq \overline{\overline{A}}$ (where $\overline{A}$ denotes the *closure* of $A$). Thus, the accumulation points of $A'$ will also be accumulation points of $A$, but $A'$ may have *fewer* accumulation points than $A$ does.

In other words, you'll have that $A' \supset A'' \supset A''' \ldots$. This means that have to start with a set with "enough" accumulation points, otherwise you'll hit the empty set too early for $A',A'',A'''$ to be all different. The easiest way to avoid that is to work backwards, i.e. start with $A'''$, as Asaf suggested.

Let $$
  A''' = \{(0,0)\} \text{.}
$$ Then construct some $A'' \supset A'''$ such that $A''$ has accumulation point $(0,0)$, say $$
  A'' = \{(\frac{1}{n},0) \,:\, n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{(0,0)\} \text{.}
$$
Now continue this idea to find $A'$. $A'$ will have to contain sequences which converge to $(\frac{1}{n},0))$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Finally, from $A'$, determine $A$.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @JohnMichael I tried to explain the idea a bit more verbosely...

Comment: Sorry, there was an error and only half of your answer appeared!

Comment: @JohnMichael No error, I expanded it after reading your comment, figuring I should explain things better...