# Derivative of the derivative of a set

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Suppose that we have a non-empty set called $X\subseteq \Bbb R$. The derivative $DX\neq \emptyset$ (I not want to consider particular cases - see the comments -) of a set [is constituted by](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DerivedSet.html) the accumulation points of $X$.
But if I consider $D(D(X))$, i.e. the derivative of the derivative of $X$, surely it's still a derivative set.

> Is it possible it could be $D(D(X))\subseteq DX$? What happens if is there a sequence of derivative sets? In other words, is it possible that
> $$D(D(D(\cdots(X))))=\emptyset$$
> if $X\neq \emptyset$ or is there always an empty-set $Y=D(D(D(\cdots(X))))\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: What subsets have you tried? You would know the answer if you have tried any.

Comment: @Chrystomath I have seen a set $A=\{-2-3/(n^2+2),\,n\in \Bbb N\}\cup[0,1]\cup[3,4]$.

Comment: Well considering any finite set or even $X=\mathbb{Z}$ you clearly have $D(\mathbb{Z})=\emptyset$

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης I totally agree with you that $\Bbb Z$ it is made of isolated points. Actually, my question is not done well.

Comment: ok then consider $A=\{m+\frac{1}{n},m\in\mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, clearly $D(A)=\mathbb{Z}$ so it is still possible

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης I am always happy to receive different answers....I have studied these concepts 26 years ago :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Never too late for a revision in basic topology I guess :)

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης  Surely....but I have always bit of the time...and I have 45 years old...and at the end of this year...46 ☹️☹️☹️☹️☹️

Comment: See the answers, comments, and links to stuff elsewhere to the Mathematics Stack Exchange question [Confusion on Derived Sets and the $n$-the Derived Set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434580/13130). The google search ["Cantor-Bendixson" + "derivatives"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cantor-Bendixson%22+%22derivatives%22) will also be helpful.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you very much much...for your contribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, googling [Cantor-Bendixson rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=Cantor%E2%80%93Bendixson%20rank,-For%20ordinal%20numbers&text=The%20transfinite%20sequence%20of%20Cantor,Cantor%E2%80%93Bendixson%20rank%20of%20X.) may help you, and if you know something about [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) you may find it easier to understand.

I don't understand your question very well. $D(D(X))\subseteq D(X)$ always holds for $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ because $D(X)$ is a closed set. I guess you may be asking whether for any $n$ there exists some $X$ such that $D^{(n)}(X)\neq\emptyset$, where $D^{(n)}(X)$ means taking derivative repeatedly for $n$ times. This is indeed possible. For some complicated $X$ it may even happen that $D^{(n)}(X)\neq\emptyset$ for **every** $n$; furthermore the intersection of all these things, namely $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}D^{(n)}(X)$, could be non-empty; call this intersection $D^{(\omega)}(X)$ and we can keep iterating, obtaining $D^{(\omega+1)}(X)$, $D^{(\omega+2)}(X)$, $D^{(\omega+\omega)}(X)$, etc.

To see why is that possible, let us first consider the simplest case when $D(X)$ contains exactly one point. An example is $X=\{-1,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4},...,-\frac{1}{2^m},...\}\cup\{0\}$. All those negative points are isolated, though they become closer and closer to each other until they "cluster" at $0$. Now $D(X)$ means to throw away all isolated points, so we have the point $0$ left, i.e., $D(X)=\{0\}.$ If we take the derivative of $D(X)$, since $0$ is clearly isolated in $\{0\}$, we have nothing left, $D(D(X))=\emptyset$.

Now to get some $Y$ such that $D(D(Y))\neq\emptyset$, we "place a copy of $X$ at every isolated point of $X$" ($X$ is same as before). It is better to imagine the picture; if written down $Y$ could be something like $X\cup\{-\frac{1}{2^m}-\frac{1}{2^{m+k}}\mid m,k\geq 1\}$. Every point in the original $X$, say $-\frac{1}{2^m}$, becomes non-isolated because it is approached by the sequence $(-\frac{1}{2^{m+k}})_{k\geq 1}$ from the left ($0$ of course remains non-isolated in $Y$), while all these new points $-\frac{1}{2^{m+k}}$ are isolated. Therefore $D(Y)=X$, and by previous paragraph we see $D(D(Y))=D(X)=\{0\}$, and $D(D(D(Y)))=\emptyset$. Using this method we can obtain set $Z$ such that $D^{(n)}(Z)$ vanishes exactly at any desired stage $n$.

To get an $X$ such that $D^{(n)}(X)$ is non-empty for every $n$, we just take the union of previously constructed $X_n$ such that $D^{(n)}(X_n)$ is non-empty, that is $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ ,and notice that since $X\supseteq X_{n}$ for every $n$, and since $A\supseteq B$ implies $D(A)\supseteq D(B)$, we have $D^{(n)}(X)$ non-empty for every $n$.

In essence, what we are doing is just mapping countable ordinal numbers into the real line. The order type of the $X$ defined above is called $\omega+1$, because there are $\omega$ or infinitely many points (those $-\frac{1}{2^{m}}$'s) followed by one point (which is $0$). The order type of $Y$ is $\omega$-many $X$'s followed by a point, and therefore is $\omega\times\omega+1$, also denoted as $\omega^{2}+1$, etc. By the so called  [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) we can map any countable ordinal $\alpha$ into the real line, and thus obtain $X$ such that $D^{(\alpha)}(X)$ vanishes exactly at any desired stage $\alpha$.

Comment: +1 for a nice answer that I didn't have time to attempt, and apparently which no one else did until now. Possibly you already know this, but this idea of limit points of limit points of limit points etc. is the actual concept G. Cantor was dealing with when he began his excursions into transfinite notions in the early 1870s. See the references in [these comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361862/what-are-some-examples-of-theorem-requiring-highly-subtle-hypothesis/361890#comment912727_361890).

Comment: Thank you very much...for your answer. I have not understood nothing...But it is not important ahah. :-) and I have appreciated also your effort.