# Example verification: $E$ and $E'$ might not have the same limit points

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

> Let $E'$ be the set of all limit points of a set $E$.
>
> Do $E$ and $E'$ always have the same limit points?

Proof:
$E''\subset E'$ because $E'$ is closed.

But inclusion $E'\subset E''$ is false. We can take $\mathbb{R}^1$ with metric $\rho(x,y)=|x-y|$ and set $E=\{1/n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then $E'=\{0\}$ but $E''=\varnothing$.

---

Is my example true?

Comment: That is the exact counterexample I thought of. Yeah, looks good.

Comment: Yes, this is fine. And it can be extended to get $E''$ different from both $E'$ and $E$, and so on: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401323/accumulation-points-of-accumulation-points-of-accumulation-points) and its answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your counterexample is about as good as it gets.

Interestingly, one can investigate the behaviour of iterating the operation $'$. A key phrase in this direction is **Cantor-Bendixson rank**.