# Is the fact true that compact set is in perfect set?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

By definition,

> Perfect set $E_1$ is closed set without isolated points.
>
> Compact set $E_2$ is bounded and closed set in Euclidean space; $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is the following equation true?
$$E_2 \subseteq E_1$$

---

In my understanding, examples of perfect set;
$$
\mathbb{R}^n, [10, \infty), [-10, 20] \cup [30, 40], \mbox{Cantor set}, [(0,0) (20, \infty)], \cdots
$$

and examples of compact set;
$$
[10, 20], [-7, -2]\cup[0, 5], [(10, 20), (15, 23)], \cdots
$$

---

In a nutshell, my question is whether every compact set is perfect.

In addition, are there any problems in my examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p\in\Bbb R^n$, the set $\{p\}$ is compact but not perfect, since $p$ is an isolated point. The same is true of any finite set. There are also infinite compact sets that are not perfect; a simple example in $\Bbb R$ is $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, in which $0$ is the only non-isolated point.

Comment: Ah, isolated points could be compact!!!! Except isolated point cases, every compact set is perfect?

Comment: In my opinion, $\left\{\cdots, -\frac{1}{2}, -1, 0, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \cdots\right\}$ is not closed and not bounded. So this set is not compact by the ***Heine-Borel theorem***, isn't it?

Comment: @Danny: It’s more complicated than that. Take a look at my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401323/accumulation-points-of-accumulation-points-of-accumulation-points/401337#401337), The diagram shows a compact set in $\Bbb R^2$. If you remove the isolated points, you have another compact set in $\Bbb R^2$, but it still has isolated points. Do this two more times, and you end up with a one-point space. What is true is that [every compact set either is countable or has a perfect subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property).

Comment: @Danny: Assuming that you mean the set $$\left\{-1,-\frac12,-\frac13,\ldots,0,\ldots,\frac13,\frac12,1\right\}\;,$$ you’re set is bounded — it’s a subset of $[-1,1]$ — and closed — its only limit point is $0$, which is in the set — so it’s compact.

Comment: Ah, thank you!!! I got my fault, now I totally agree with that the set is bounded. And now, I am pondering about the set is closed or not. I agree with the union of isolated points are closed, but I want to check near zero point.

Comment: @Danny_Kim The point is that the only "weird" point - precisely, the only point which is a limit of a sequence of points from the set - is zero, and since zero is in the set, that means the set is closed.

Comment: The set {1/n} has 1 limit point.  That limit point is 0.  The set {1/n} U {0} has the same limit point.  0 is in {1/}U {0} so it is closed.  BTW don't say "in my opinion" in math.  Either you are right or you are wrong.  Your opinion has nothing to do with it.